# Excel: Copy Values automaticly from one sheet to another via conditional formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose

I need to transpose a Excel Table.
How can i execute the following rule via Excel Commands:

If 2 cells match on different sheets check if another cell in this row matches with one header cell in the second sheet and then get value from another cell in this row. take a look at the images.

[image: First Sheet: Data Source]

[image: Second Sheet: Data Target]

Comment: https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your given example you can try below formula. Once the formula will work in same sheet then you can adjust the formula to work on another sheet. Then you you need to add sheet name before ranges.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$10,SUMPRODUCT(ROW($A$2:$A$10)*($A$2:$A$10=$F2)*($B$2:$B$10=G$1))-1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro! Thats it :)